# Задача на время работы, ошибка в коде

Tags: python

Условие задачи следующее:
В фирме решили учесть рабочее время своих сотрудников. Для этого по каждому сотруднику собирается информацию, показывающая время его прихода и ухода с работы. Напишите программу, получающую на вход строчку, состоящую из записей вида ВРЕМЯ_ПРИХОДА-ВРЕМЯ_УХОДА, разделённых пробелами, и возвращающую три числа: число дней, которое работник выходил на работу, а также число часов и минут, которое он провёл в офисе. Время прихода и ухода задано в формате h:m, 0 ≤ h < 24, 0 ≤ m < 60, уход всегда не раньше прихода.

Пример ввода:
7:45-14:30 8:00-12:18

Вывод:
2 11 3

Мой код, приведённый ниже (заранее прошу прощения, я только начал изучать питон) выдаёт ошибку на 5ом тесте, не подскажете в чём проблема, пожалуйста?

```
string = input()

help_string = string.split()

days = len(help_string)
hrs = 0
mins = 0

for i in range(days):
       help_1 = help_string[i].index(':')
       start_hrs = int(help_string[i][0 : help_1])
       ##print(start_hrs)

       help_2 = help_string[i][help_1 : help_1 + 4].index('-') + help_1
       start_mins = int(help_string[i][help_1 + 1 : help_2])
       ##print(start_mins)

       help_1 = help_string[i][help_2 : help_2 + 4].index(':') + help_2
       finish_hrs = int(help_string[i][help_2 + 1: help_1])
       ##print(finish_hrs)

       finish_mins = int(help_string[i][help_1 + 1 : ])
       ##print(finish_mins)

       hrs += finish_hrs - start_hrs - 1
       mins += finish_mins + (60 - start_mins)

if mins > 60:
        hrs += mins // 60
        mins -= (mins // 60) * 60

if hrs > 24:
       days += hrs // 24
       hrs -= (hrs // 24) * 24

print(days, hrs, mins)
```

Comment: У вас при вставке кода отступы съехали. Поправьте, а то в таком виде код очень сложно разобрать.

Comment: Да, прошу прощения, сразу не заметил

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ваш код косячит на случаях, когда в итоговом времени получается круглое количество часов. Например, для случая 7:00-10:00 ваш код выдаёт ответ 2 часа и 60 минут.

Кажется, что это можно решить просто заменив в строчке

```
if mins > 60:
```

строгое неравенство на `>=`

Comment: И ещё я совершенно не понял, зачем вы делаете то, что вы делаете при количестве часов больше 24. У вас же в days количество дней, в которые работник ходил на работу и вы их уже посчитали, разве нет? Зачем вы добавляете к ним ещё что-то?

Comment: Да, это лишнее, теперь работает